# How to Integrate ionic-datepicker by rajeshwarpatlolla in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to integrate [`ionic-datepicker` by rajeshwarpatlolla](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker) in my Ionic project.

I already followed the instruction given on the page but I am confused as to how to add the dependency in my app.module.js?

My app has pages like home page and other pages. So, how can this library be added to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to add an Ionic 1 plugin into an Ionic 3 project. You could try the [ionic2-datepicker](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic2-datepicker) also by Rajesh Warpatlolla as that is designed for Ionic 2/3 projects. He does say it is in development so it may not do what you want.

Comment: ok i got it.. Thanks for reply. can you suggest me any other plugin like that.. if possible..!

Comment: I would recommend the ionic-native date-picker that was designed for Ionic. Less likely to give you compatibility problems.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/